# cross apply / logic, not working properly

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this problem I cannot solve alone and I would be glad to receive your help
I have this table called ProductDeliveryRules:

[ProductDeliveryRules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQWzV.png)

This table contains the rules to give a product the destination country where it could be bought.
For example, the products with CategoryId 12 (first rule) will have the country 'IT'
The products with DepartmentId 10 AND SupplierTypeId 1 **(both conditions need to be meet because they have the same Rule Group=5)**
**In the case the Product meets multiple RuleGroup conditions, only the rule with the lowest RulePriority must be considered for the product.**
If the product meet no RuleGroup then the default Country is '**' which mean all countries

```
 SELECT i.ProductId, 
           ValidRule.RuleGroup --NULL IF NO RULE GROUP CONDITIONS ARE MET
    FROM inserted i
    join Brand b on b.IDBrand = i.IDBrand
    join Suppliers s on s.SupplierId = b.SupplierId

    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM ProductDeliveryRules pdr2
            WHERE pdr2.RuleGroup = PDR.RuleGroup
            AND (
                (PDR2.[KeyType] = 'CategoryId' AND PDR2.[Key] != i.IDCategory)
                OR
                (PDR2.[KeyType] = 'MaxWeight' AND i.param <= PDR2.[Key])
                OR
                (PDR2.[KeyType] = 'DepartmentId' AND PDR2.[Key] != i.IDDepartment)
                OR
                (PDR2.[KeyType] = 'SupplierTypeId' AND PDR2.[Key] != f.IDSupplierType)
            )
        ) 
        THEN PDR.RuleGroup ELSE NULL END as RuleGroup
        FROM ProductDeliveryRules PDR
        ORDER BY
    PDR.RulePriority ASC
    ) AS ValidRule
```

The code doesn't return the right RuleGroup, I don't know why, I'm trying for several days

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with C#...

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots. Copy your data and paste it into the request. As to "doesn't return the right RuleGroup", please give us sample data, the result you get and the result you want to get instead. It would be great, did you even create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). On first glance: shouldn't it be `AND i.param > PDR2.[Key]`?

Comment: @thorstenkettner I used the inverse Logic to get the rulegroup which none of the rules with the same rulegroup do not match. (Because rule group 5 Is composed of 2 rules, both have the same rulegroup)

Comment: Yes, but if the rule is called MaxWeight, shouldn't the Key be the maximum weight? So in order to match the rule, the weight would have to be <= Key. And the inverse of it is weight > Key.

Comment: I have posted an answer. However, again: Please remove the image link and add the data as text to your request. It was a nuisance not to be able to just copy it to my editor. And without this table your request is incomplete, Future readers that don't see your image won't benefit from this stackoverflow request.

Comment: By the way: You should avoid key words for column names. By naming your column [Key], you force yourself to use brackets whenever you deal with this column.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you used an `EXISTS`. You just need to query the table directly, and use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY` to allow cases where a row is not found.

From your comments it seems you want to check a whole `RuleGroup` at once. So you need to group inside the subquery, then check if the whole group has all matched.

```sql
SELECT
  i.ProductId, 
  ValidRule.RuleGroup --NULL IF NO RULE GROUP CONDITIONS ARE MET
FROM inserted i
join Brand b on b.IDBrand = i.IDBrand
join Suppliers s on s.SupplierId = b.SupplierId
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      pdr.RuleGroup
    FROM ProductDeliveryRules pdr
    GROUP BY
      pdr.RulePriority,
      pdr.RuleGroup
    -- check if the number of matches = number of rules in the group
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN
            (pdr.KeyType = 'CategoryId' AND pdr.[Key] != i.IDCategory)
            OR
            (pdr.KeyType = 'MaxWeight' AND i.param <= pdr.[Key])
            OR
            (pdr.KeyType = 'DepartmentId' AND pdr.[Key] != i.IDDepartment)
            OR
            (pdr.KeyType = 'SupplierTypeId' AND pdr.[Key] != f.IDSupplierType)
           THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
    ORDER BY
      pdr.RulePriority
) AS ValidRule;
```

The reason for the extra joins at the beginning is unclear.

Comment: Because otherwise It doesnt work for rules which have the same rulegroup, in that case all rules with the same rulegroup must be meet

Comment: I used the exists because I used the inverse Logic to get the rulegroup which none of the rules with the same rulegroup do not match. (Because rule group 5 Is composed of 2 rules, both have the same rulegroup)

Comment: See edits. But what do you want if you have two rules with the same `RuleGroup` but different `RulePriority`?

Comment: It wont happen because i set the rulepriority the same

Comment: Sounds like you should really normalize and break that table up into `ProductDeliveryRule` and `ProductDeliveryRuleGroup`

Answer (score 0):

For every row in your table you examine for every rule whether all its rule group conditions are fulfilled or not. It would suffice to check every rule group once, but it isn't an issue that you are doing it multifold for groups containing more than one rule.

The approach is generally good, but let's look at it in detail. Per rule you select one value, namely the RuleGroup when all its group's rules are matched and null otherwise. Then you order the rules by RulePriority and take the top result row. In other words you always select the result for IDRule 15, because it has the lowest RulePriority (10). You don't consider any other rules. This means you only check the MaxWeight, because that's what this rule (group) is about. (And I even think you have the condition inverted by mistake.)

The main point is that the `NOT EXISTS (<a rule mismatch>)` must be a *limiting* clause. It belongs in `WHERE`, so you only get rule groups that match. Only then order these by priority and take the top row.

As to the data model: You are lacking a rule group table, because it's a rule group, not a rule that has a priority and a result value. (Imagine two rules in the same group with different resulting countries - it would make no sense.) I am starting my query by creating the missing rule group table on-the-fly, but you should really change your database and split the ProductDeliveryRules table into two.

```
WITH
  rule_group AS
  (
    SELECT
      rulegroup,
      MAX(value) AS group_value,
      MAX(rulepriority) AS group_priority
    FROM productdeliveryrules
    GROUP BY rulegroup
  )
SELECT
  i.productid,
  COALESCE(best.group_value, '**') AS country_code
FROM inserted i
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM rule_group rg
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 'a rule mismatch'
    FROM productdeliveryrules r
    WHERE r.rulegroup = rg.rulegroup
    AND 
    (
      (r.keytype = 'CategoryId' AND r.[key] != i.idcategory)
      OR
      (r.keytype = 'MaxWeight' AND r.[key] < i.param)
      OR
      (r.keytype = 'DepartmentId' AND r.[key] != i.iddepartment)
      OR
      (r.keytype = 'SupplierTypeId' AND r.[key] != i.idsuppliertype)
    )
  ) 
  ORDER BY rg.group_priority
) best
ORDER BY i.productid;
```